# Possible issue when publishing app that uses Google Play Services in China?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-games

I currently have a game app made with `Unity` that is published on the Google Play Store. The game utilizes Google Play Games for the Achievements and Leaderboards.

Now I plan to publish my game on the Chinese Android app stores.

I understand that Google is blocked in China. Not all Android phones there support or come installed with the Google Play services that my app requires.

My question and main concern is will my app crash on those devices that do not have the Google Play services?

Comment: If your app requires it, the app will most likely not be able to run without it.

Answer (score 3):

As previously stated, your application won't crash if the device has pre-installed Google Services (i.e. the phone was purchased outside of mainland China).

However, this won't be the case for 99% of all Chinese users' devices, so it won't be accessible to them.

The only solution is to modify your game, remove Google Play Services and implement local game stores solutions for the achievements and leaderboards.

Answer (score 1):

Almost all of Android phones in China are highly customized by different Manufacturers. If google play service is required, it may crash on some phones.

Answer (score 0):

Provided the Google Play Services are installed on the device, your application won't crash.  The issue is that Google services are not available in China, such as Google+ and Drive, both of which are used by Play Services so these calls will fail.